# Should I compress _id key on Mongo schema

Tags: mongodb

I have to store millions of documents in a Mongo database collection.

These documents are social media posts and they can be identified with a URN, there are three types of URN :

- urn:cp:postType**A**:*numericalId*
- urn:cp:postType**B**:*numericalId*
- urn:cp:postType**C**:*numericalId*

I plan to use these urns as `_id` but it seems to be a waste of resources to store them as this. This is why I would like to store a shortened version like `a:numericalId`, `b:numericalId` and `c:numericalId`
But I am not sure this is a good idea because:

- Maybe I should let Mongo handle the compression for me (I am using WiredTiger)
- (I will have to compute the real URN when exposing the data)

What is your opinion?

Comment: What's the advantage of compressing the Mongodb ID? you can make another expression to generate a short ID for each document like A0001? A0002 etc ..

Comment: @RebaiAhmed to save disk/memory space.